# Perl Catch Variable in Error

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script and I am trying to make it print out the value for $article when it errors.  The script looks like:

```
eval{
    for my $article($output =~ m/<value lang_id="">(.*?)<\/value>/g)
    { 
        $article =~ s/ /+/g;
        $agent->get("someurl");

        $agent->follow_link(url_regex => qr/(?i:pdf)/ );

        my $pdf_data = $agent->content;
        open my $ofh, '>:raw', "$article.pdf"
        or die "Could not write: $!";
        print {$ofh} $pdf_data;
        close $ofh;
        sleep 10;
    }
};
if($@){
    print "error: ...: $@\n";
}
```

So if there is no .pdf file the code sends an error which is what I want.  But what I need to know is it somehow possible to get the name of the $article that caused the error?  I was trying to use some kind of global variable with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you put the eval inside the for loop? Something like this:

```
for my $article($output =~ m/<value lang_id="">(.*?)<\/value>/g)
{ 
   $article =~ s/ /+/g;
   eval{
      # ...
   }
   if ($@) {
      print STDERR "Error handling article: ", $article, " ", $!, "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I do that it prints every pdf not just the ones equal to $article from the for loop

Comment: ITYM `print STDERR "Error handling article $article: $@\n";` (not `$!`).  And you can use `warn` instead of `print STDERR`.  But in general, this _should_ work; if it doesn't work for @chrstahl89, the problem is probably somewhere inside the eval.

Comment: @chrstahl89: Can you post the actual code that "prints every pdf"?

Comment: Posted it to my original question

Comment: It was my code that was wrong in another part, this was the correct solution I just did not know it at the time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If that's your *only* problem, just declare `my $article;` before the eval, and remove the `my` from the `for` loop.  But from your reply to Cornel Ghiban, I suspect it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Include the file name in the `die>/ string:`

```
open my $ofh, '>:raw', "$article.pdf" or die "Could not write '$article': $!";
```

I assume that you want to write and not read.  Unless you have a permission issue or a full file system, a write is likely to succeed and you will never see an error.

Comment: This will not work because the error is from getting the link, it never goes to write.

Comment: That wasn't clear to me in your original question.  That said, follow-link returns undef when the page has no links or the link can;t be found. You could throw an exception for that.

Comment: I think that will be the answer, just have to figure out how to throw an error for that.  Well catch the error...it already throws it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not need to die, you can just set a flag or save message to the log or store error for late handling.

```
my @errors=();
................
open my $ofh, '>:raw', "$article.pdf" or do { push @errors,"$article: $!" };
if(-e $ofh) {
    # work with the file
}
................
if(@errors) {
    # do something
}
```